# Netbeans mark occurrences highlight stopped working

Tags: php, netbeans, highlight

I've been using this awesome Netbeans feature for a long time now and I got pretty used to it. When you select a variable/function/whatever it is supposed to highlight all it's other occurrences but my Netbeans stopped doing that. I can however scroll through the occurrences with ALT + UP or ALT + DOWN, so the feature is working, but I just don't see the highlight.

Also, I am missing the categories from Tools/Options/Fonts&Colors/Syntax
[image: Missing categories]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to run your NetBeans installation with a clean user dir http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir
- Try a different syntax highlighting theme.

Comment: It works in a clean user dir. But I've tried exporting and importing those settings and I still have the same problem, there's no category showing when I select PHP as a language, and therefore I cannot edit anything